# laravel 5.1 Form::select add value

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5.1

I am in trouble.

laravel under 5.0 code

testController.php

```
$prefs = ['' => 'Please Select'] + Prefectures::lists('name', 'id');
    :
    :
```

test.blade.php

```
{{ Form::select('pref', $prefs, null) }}
```

However, in laravel 5.0 or more, it is an error in this code.
the blade file even if the following result was the same.

test.blade.php

```
{!! Form::select('pref', $prefs, null) !!}
```

I want to create an array that you added one item to the obtained values from the database.

Answer (score 1):

controller

```
$prefs = ['' => 'Please Select'] + Prefectures::lists('name', 'id');
```

view

```
{!! Form::select('pref', $prefs, null) !!}
```

double curly bracket will escape. so coming from laravel 4.0 you should change {{ to {!!. I was also confused before when i migrated to 5.0.

this should work fine.

**Update**
This what i usually do in my code.

```
$prefs = Prefectures::lists('name', 'id');
return view('view', compact('prefs'));


{!! Form::select('pref', ['' => 'Please Select'] + $prefs, null) !!}
```

Comment: $prefs = ['' => 'Please Select'] + Prefectures::lists('name', 'id');　Error occurs in this code.　"Unsupported operand types"

Answer (score 0):

Another solution.

```
{!! Form::select('posts',
    [null => 'Title'] + json_decode($posts->pluck('title', 'id'), true), null)
!!}
```

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar el método prepend.

```
$departments = Department::lists('name', 'id')->prepend('Please Select');
```

Comment: You need to explain your answer. Blocks of code are not good answers.